Node Express server returning EADDRNOTAVAIL error when trying to host on 192.168.0.90:3000
when trying to run:
app.listen("3000", "192.168.0.90", () => {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${PORT}/`);
});

it returns the error:
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.0.90:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1723:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1937:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1767:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
  errno: -4090,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '192.168.0.90',
  port: 3000
}

I have tried having the hostname as 0.0.0.0, no result. I'm trying to open the page using [IP]:3000, port 3000 is portforwarded, AI and older posts haven't fixed the issue at all.
